# Find minimum algorithm complexity

Tags: matrices, algorithms, binary

So, I have this task:
Let us have square matrix $A \ size\ n\ \times\ n$ for which is true:
$$A(k,l)<=A(m,p)\  if \ k <=m, l<=p$$
I need to find algorithm, which finds value X in such matrix, which is not very hard, it combination of binary search, first to find row(or column), and then binary search in row(or column) which will be $~nlog(n)$. But second task is: **prove that there is no algorithm which will do it for $O(n)$ time complexity** that is the point where I'm stuck. I know how to calculate complexity of some algorithm, but I don't know how to prove that my algorithm is fastest.

Thank you!

Comment: Size $n$ meaning that it is $n \times n$?

Comment: Yes, I think, I'll change it to $n\ \times\ n$

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not correct. The problem can actually be solved in $O(n)$.

Consider the following algorithm: Find the matrix element by starting in the top right corner at element $A(1, n)$ and moving towards the lower left corner $A(n, 1)$. In each step return $A(k,l)$ if $X=A(k,l)$, move left (i.e. decrease $l$) if $X>A(k,l)$ and move down (i.e. increase $k$) if $A(k,l)<X$.

Too see that this works, consider the upper right submatrix with elements $A(i,j)$ for   $i=1,\ldots,k$ and $j=l,\ldots,n$ for $A(k,l)=X$. When walking from $A(1,n)$ towards $A(n,1)$, we are leaving the upper right submatrix along the row or column where $X$ lies. We must pass $X$, because on the row where $X$ lies all elements on the right side of $X$ are large then $X$, so each step is a left move. In the same way if we are on one of the elements in the column where $X$ lies, each following step will be a down move.

See also [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-in-row-wise-and-column-wise-sorted-matrix/).